# Some machines can't ping CentOS server

Tags: windows, networking, centos

I have a CentOS 5 server. I have 20 computers. All of them are plugged into same switch running Windows XP. I can ping from 14 of them, but 6 won't ping the server. I checked the 6 that won't ping the server and there is no firewall. The server's IP address is `192.168.1.2`. I can ping the gateway which is `192.168.1.1` from those computers, but I can't ping the server. My iptables are turned off. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You say "wont ping server"... what error do you get when you try?  just no response?

Comment: it just times out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchange ip address of a non-ping pc with a ok-ping pc. So you can know if the problem is into workstation or into server.

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot ping by name, or by IP? This'll identify a name resolution issue, if you can ping by IP.
2. What's the network subnet setting on each machine, and the server? Are they all definitely within the same subnet?
3. Can you ping the workstations from the server side?

Comment: i can not ping by ip address. subnet is same all across. cannot ping from the server or to server from those machines

Answer (score 1):

Try running a packet trace while you're attempting to ping.  If you run a simultaneous packet trace on the machine and the server and compare the logs, you should get an idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the 6 PCs can ping to/from any other machines within the same LAN.
2. Check the network card and Ethernet cables of the 6 PCs.
3. Check the switch port which if it is faulty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the switch.
Try to swap UTP cables at the switch end from PC that can PING  with PC than can not ping.

What gives "tracert 192.168.1.2" and "tracert 192.168.1.1" 
As already Chris Thorpe said - what are the IP addreses of these 6 PC and what are the masks on these PC and your server ?